# Как очистить ResultSet от тегов с помощью BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup

Добрый день! Я получил html-код страницы с помощью библиотеки bs4, но не понимаю как убрать теги чтобы остался только текст. Как это сделать? Пример кода:

```
url = 'http://www.wilo.ru/glavnaja-stranica/#.WPhjgtiweUk'
headers = {'User-agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0'}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
data = dict()
data['Date'] = soup.select(".news-list-date")
data['Title'] = soup.select(".news-list-subheader")
```

Так выглядит результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А нужно чтобы только даты остались.

Я попробовал еще вариант с использованием pandas. Идея была методом replace удалить ненужные теги, но почему-то тип данных Nan возвращается. Вот пример кода:

```
url = 'http://www.wilo.ru/glavnaja-stranica/#.WPhjgtiweUk'
headers = {'User-agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0'}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
data = dict()
data['Date'] = soup.select(".news-list-date")
data['Title'] = soup.select(".news-list-subheader")

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df['Date'] = df['Date'].str.replace('<span class="news-list-date">', '')
df
```

и результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

data['Date'] = soup.select(".news-list-date").text

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так.

Python 2.x:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'http://www.wilo.ru/glavnaja-stranica/#.WPhjgtiweUk'
headers = {'User-agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0'}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)

for t in soup.findAll('span', {'class': 'news-list-date'}):
    print (t.string)
```

Python3:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'http://www.wilo.ru/glavnaja-stranica/#.WPhjgtiweUk'
headers = {'User-agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0'}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

for t in soup.findAll('span', {'class': 'news-list-date'}):
    print (t.string)
```

Ну и вместо `print (t.string)` вставьте свое, что там надо

Comment: Легче уже регулярку написать)

Comment: @stxdtm, ваш код возвращает ошибку: "type object 'BeautifulSoup' has no attribute 'BeautifulSoup'". И в целом я согласен с Alban, что регулярка, наверное легче.

Comment: это не ошибка, просто не bs4, другая версия;) добавил код целиком

Comment: @stxdtm, теперь не импортируется: No module named 'BeautifulSoup'. Вы для Python2 код пишите? У меня Python3, если это имеет значение.

Comment: @DenisNovik, да, пример был для python2. Отредактировал ответ, проверьте вариант для python3

Comment: @stxdtm, супер! Спасибо большое, очень здорово получается!

Comment: @DenisNovik, пожалуйста)

Answer (score 1):

Используйте модуль `re`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{4}') # Или \d{2}.\d{2}.\d{4}, или \d+.\d+.\d+
data['Date'] = re.findall(pattern, str(soup.select(".news-list-date")))
```

Результат:

```
['30.03.2017', '21.03.2017', '07.03.2017', '28.02.2017', '17.01.2017', '29.12.2016', '27.12.2016', '21.12.2016', '16.12.2016',
 '14.12.2016', '08.12.2016', '25.10.2016', '13.10.2016', '04.10.2016', '06.09.2016', '30.08.2016', '08.08.2016', '28.07.2016',
 '15.07.2016', '29.06.2016', '17.05.2016', '10.05.2016', '04.05.2016', '01.04.2016', '16.03.2016', '09.03.2016', '23.12.2015',
 '07.08.2015', '20.04.2015', '06.04.2015', '20.03.2015', '13.03.2015', '10.03.2015', '06.03.2015', '03.03.2015', '27.02.2015',
 '25.02.2015', '20.02.2015', '16.02.2015', '30.01.2015', '12.01.2015', '30.12.2014', '22.12.2014', '15.12.2014', '03.12.2014',
 '24.11.2014', '17.11.2014', '10.11.2014', '29.10.2014', '20.10.2014', '12.09.2014', '09.09.2014', '05.09.2014', '18.08.2014',
 '08.08.2014', '14.07.2014', '16.06.2014', '02.06.2014', '30.05.2014', '28.05.2014', '21.05.2014', '12.05.2014', '05.05.2014',
 '30.04.2014', '28.04.2014', '17.04.2014', '10.04.2014', '04.04.2014', '02.04.2014', '28.03.2014', '26.03.2014', '18.03.2014',
 '14.03.2014', '13.03.2014', '07.03.2014', '05.03.2014', '28.02.2014', '19.02.2014', '16.02.2014', '11.02.2014', '05.02.2014',
 '29.01.2014', '22.01.2014', '15.01.2014', '31.12.2013', '26.12.2013', '23.12.2013', '20.12.2013', '18.12.2013', '12.12.2013',
 '06.12.2013', '25.11.2013', '22.11.2013', '21.11.2013', '10.11.2013', '30.10.2013', '15.10.2013', '14.10.2013', '07.10.2013',
 '03.10.2013', '02.10.2013', '24.09.2013', '23.09.2013', '11.09.2013', '03.09.2013', '02.09.2013', '29.08.2013', '06.08.2013',
 '19.07.2013', '17.07.2013', '15.07.2013', '28.06.2013', '26.06.2013', '25.06.2013', '21.06.2013', '10.06.2013', '05.06.2013',
 '28.05.2013', '21.05.2013', '13.05.2013', '13.05.2013', '09.05.2013', '07.05.2013', '16.04.2013', '19.03.2013', '07.03.2013',
 '06.03.2013', '12.02.2013', '28.12.2012', '26.12.2012', '25.12.2012', '11.12.2012', '06.12.2012', '18.11.2012', '13.11.2012',
 '07.11.2012', '16.10.2012', '09.10.2012', '04.10.2012', '27.09.2012', '27.09.2012', '13.09.2012', '07.09.2012', '07.09.2012',
 '02.08.2012', '30.07.2012', '20.06.2012', '14.06.2012', '06.06.2012', '04.06.2012', '28.05.2012', '21.05.2012', '03.05.2012',
 '16.04.2012', '05.04.2012', '12.03.2012']
```

Comment: спасибо. Я так понимаю, других способов нет, кроме регулярных выражений? Дело в том, что это я в примере привел столбец с датами, но есть и другие столбцы с текстом, ссылками. Под них тоже регулярки писать?

Comment: @DenisNovik Возможно есть и иные способы, подождем еще ответов :)