# Как парсить ссылки вложенных тегов с помощью BS4?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautiful-soup

Всем привет! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как собрать все ссылки "links what I need" с помощью BS4 примерно из такой структуры:

```
<div class=’General’>
  <div class=’First class’>
    <a href=’links what I need’></a>    
  </div>
</div>
```

В документации BS4 никак не могу понять, как обратиться к этим ссылкам.

Comment: Я Вам вчера отвечал на Ваш [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/656115/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-resultset-%d0%be%d1%82-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-beautifulsoup). Замените `'span'` на `'a'`, а `'class': 'news-list-date'` на `'href': 'links what I need'`

Comment: @stxdtm, я новичек в этом вопросе, поэтому законмерности пока плохо нахожу, извините. Я не понял один момент в вашем комментарии. Вместо links what I need может стоять 150 других ссылок в коде сайта. То есть стандартный код: a href="какая-то ссылка на страницу". Как это в коде парсера отразить?

Comment: если нет необходимости искать точное совпадение по атрибуту href - просто уберите эту часть из кода. оставьте `soup.findAll('span')`. Тогда в результате будут абсолютно все ссылки со страницы, собственно, это Вам и предлагают в ответе ниже

Comment: @stxdtm, спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Имеем к примеру шаблон:

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Example</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class='General'>
   <div class='First-class'>
    <p><a href='links what I need'>Link - links what I need</a></p>
    <p><a href='links what I'>Link - links what I</a></p> 
    <p><a href='links what'>Link - links what</a></p>
    <p><a href='links'>Link - links</a></p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Что бы получить всё что в теге `<a href='...'></a>`:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = urllib.request.urlopen('http://your/url')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser').find('div', class_='First-class')
for i in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    print(i['href'])
```

Результат:

```
links what I need
links what I
links what
links
```

Вариант с **Regular expression**:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'href="(.*)">')
html = urllib.request.urlopen('http://your/url')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser').find('div', class_='First-class')
print(re.findall(pattern, str(soup)))
```

Результат:

```
['links what I need', 'links what I', 'links what', 'links']
```

Comment: И кстати, у вас кавычки - не кавычки :)

Comment: знаю, это просто схема тегов для примера)

Comment: спасибо за понятный пример!

Comment: Можно использовать `find('div', 'First-class')` (`class_` можно не указывать) и `find_all('a', href=True)` (чтобы гарантировать наличие href атрибута).

Comment: @DenisNovik могу еще добавить вариант с регулярным выражением если интересует.

Comment: @Alban, напишите, пожалуйста!